# How to reshape a matrix

Tags: r, reshape

I have a matrix (d) that looks like:

```
d <- 
as.matrix(read.table(text = "
    month    Q1    Q2   Q3    Q4    Q5    Q6    Q7    Q8    Q9   Q10   Q11   Q12   Q13         
X10    10  7.04  8.07  9.4  8.17  9.39  8.13  9.43  9.06  8.59  9.37  9.79  8.47  8.86  
X11    11 12.10 11.50 12.6 13.70 11.90 11.50 13.10 17.20 19.00 14.60 13.70 13.20 16.10  
X12    12 24.00 22.00 22.2 20.50 21.60 22.50 23.10 23.30 30.50 34.10 36.10 37.40 28.90 
X1      1 18.30 16.30 16.2 14.80 16.60 15.40 15.20 14.80 16.70 14.90 15.00 13.80 15.90  
X2      2 16.70 14.40 15.3 14.10 15.50 16.70 15.20 16.10 18.00 26.30 28.00 31.10 34.20",
header=TRUE))
```

going from Q1 to Q31 (its the days in each month). what I would like to get is:

```
month day Q
10    1   7.04
10    2   8.07
```

and so on for the 31 days and the 12 months.

I have tried using the following code:

```
reshape(d, direction="long", varying = list(colnames(d)[2:32]), v.names="Q", idvar="month", timevar="day")
```

but I get the error :

`Error in d[, timevar] <- times[1L] : subscript out of bounds`

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with the code? I don't really understand the help file on "reshape", it's a bit confusing... Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost there - you're just missing `as.data.frame(d)` to make your matrix into a data frame. Also you don't need the list in `varying` - just a vector, so

```
reshape(as.data.frame(d), varying=colnames(d)[2:32], v.names="Q", 
        direction="long", idvar="month", timevar="day")
```

Comment: This still needs one more bit, `sep = ""`, for `reshape()` to properly handle the column names in `varying`...

Comment: @JoshO'Brien since `v.names` is specified, `reshape` is not trying to determine the names from the original column names, so `sep` isn't needed.

Comment: @BrianDiggs -- This is maddening! Can you confirm that you've run the above code with the matrix of data read in in the OP's code box? Because it doesn't work for me, and if it does for you, something really strange is going on. I'm running R-2.14.1 on Windows, and I can't imagine why something as 'core' as `reshape()` would be behaving differently on our two boxes. Hmmm.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien It doesn't exactly work; the original question was about a matrix that had 32 columns (month + Q1 through Q31), but the example data only has 14 (month + Q1 through Q13), so the code here doesn't work on the example `d` without error.  Change `2:32` to `2:14` and it does for me. The output is sorted in a different order (month within day, rather than day within month), but that can be sorted out (pardon the pun) afterwards. I am also using R-2.14.1 on Windows (64-bit).

Comment: @BrianDiggs Thanks for clearing that up for me. I should have known better than doubt both you and Simon Urbanek put together ;)

Answer (score 3):

The help file **is** confusing as heck, not least because (as I've learned) the necessary information almost always actually is in there --- somewhere.

As a prime example, midway through the help file, there is this bit:

> The function will
>        attempt to guess the ‘v.names’ and ‘times’ from these names [i.e. the ones in the 'varying' argument].  The
>        default is variable names like ‘x.1’, ‘x.2’, where ‘sep = "."’
>        specifies to split at the dot and drop it from the name.  To have
>        alphabetic followed by numeric times use ‘sep = ""’.

That last sentence is the one you need here: `"Q1"`, `"Q2"`, etc. are indeed "alphabetic followed by numeric", so you need to set `sep = ""` argument if `reshape()` is to know how to split apart those column names.

Try this:

```
res <- reshape(as.data.frame(d), idvar="month", timevar="day", 
               varying = -1, direction = "long", sep = "")

head(res[with(res, order(month,day)),])
#     month day    Q
# 1.1     1   1 18.3
# 1.2     1   2 16.3
# 1.3     1   3 16.2
# 1.4     1   4 14.8
# 1.5     1   5 16.6
# 1.6     1   6 15.4
```

Comment: thanks, but that doesn't seem to be the problem as it still produces an error

Comment: That's odd. Just out of curiosity, could you please take a moment to load in the data from the code box in your question, and then run my code on it?  If the data in the code box really matches your data, and it doesn't work, I'll really be stumped about what's going on!

Answer (score 2):

The help file on reshape is not a bit confusing.  It's a LOT confusing.  Assuming your matrix has 12 rows(1 for each month) and 31 columns (I'm guessing you have NA values months with fewer than 31), you could easily construct this by hand.

```
d <- data.frame(month = rep(d[,1], 31), day = rep(1:31, each = 12), Q = as.vector(d[,2:32])
```

Now, back to your reshape... I'm guessing it's not parsing the names of your columns correctly.  It might work better with Q.1, Q.2, etc.  BTW, my reshaping above really depends on what you presented actually being a matrix and not a data.frame.

Comment: thanks this also works quite well! I should have thought of dodging the reshape function after a few frustrated attempts :)